# inputting strings into a multidimensional character array?

Tags: c, arrays

While inputting the strings I am getting warnings like

```
error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'
```

In application

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[100][10];
    int s,i,k=0;
    scanf("%d",&s);
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember this : Whenever you scan a `%s` via `scanf`, don't use the & with the variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanf("%s",&a[i]);
           ^ This will pass address of `a[i]` thus giving error.
```

As  `%s` specifier expects a pointer to the first character in a character array. And using `&` with `a[i]` will evaluate `char (*)[10]`.

Instead this should be done -

```
scanf("%9s", a[i]);
```

Comment: can we use %s instead of %9s because i don't want extra spaces between strings when printing them.

Comment: @nani  Yes you can use `%s` no problem in that.

Comment: @nani  but what do you mean by `extra space`  because `%9s` will store just first 9 characters in array not more than that. So using `%s` will not harm you anyway .

Answer (score 1):

Yes because there is an difference between **array** and **pointer to an array**. You may use `char *a[100];` as a pointer to array of 100 elements and use malloc/calloc every time to allocate space dynamically. The program would look like:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>         
int main(void)
{
    char *a[100];
    int s,i,k=0;
    scanf("%d",&s);
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        a[i] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*10);
        scanf("%s",a[i]);
        printf("%s",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the 2D array in the question, which means this answer isn't all that much help — it provides an alternative mechanism, rather than fixing the preferred (and perfectly reasonable) mechanism used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

code: scanf("%s",&a[i]);

&a[i] point char **, because a is 2D char array.

code instead : scanf("%s",a[i]); will get right result

Comment: `&a[i]` is a `char(*)[10]`, not a `char**`